# Aumentar tamaño del botón en JOptionPane - Java

Tags: java, joptionpane

Quisiera **aumentar el tamaño** del botón de un `JOptionePane`. El código del `JOptionPane` del `button` es el siguiente:

```
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "¿Desea salir de la aplicación?",
                        "Gestor de clientes", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE) {
                    dispose();
                    Login login = new Login();
                    login.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Se puede aumentar el tamaño fuente del texto y los botones del `JOptionPane`?

Answer (score 2):

Para ello habría que hacer uso de un par de **JBUTTON**,los cuales reemplacen a los botones por defecto del JOptione,ya que no se puede hacer uso de ellos mas que para interactuar con los métodos que nos provee esa clase

Fuente:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Ejemplo:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Sort {
public static void main(String[] args) {
JButton button = new JButton("Si");
button.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman",  0, 30));
JButton button1 = new JButton("No");

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
       JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();
   }
});

JButton[] buttons = { button,button1 };

JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "¿Desea salir de la aplicación?","Gestor de clientes",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,
null, buttons, buttons[0]);

    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]